# DesignPattern: Partial Object creation of unknown instance members at runtime

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Currently I have an endpoint which returns a a fairly large data object.
This call for all objects of that type can generate 20MBs of data. However not always the clients need all the information in the object, quite often a subset of data is all that is required. I want to give the client the option to pass in some parameters to determine what parts of the object they require.
For example, specifying an array of restriction fields with each field itself a group of instance members on the object, a user can restict how much f the object they want. Looking at the figure Object below, restriction field value **r1** may refer to instance members **a** and **b**.

example request *"myurl/restrict=r1,r2"*

```
MyObject(){
a;
b;
c;
d;
e;
f;
g;
h;
.... many more fields
}
```

So with that in mind, I created an ENUM to model the restriction fields and the subset of instance members which each instance field represents.
Now on the DB query I want to use the ENUM(s) values to decide which parts of the object I want.

So the select query will select the Object and the object can be partially instantiated by calling whatever get/set methods are required. I have implemented this on the query side by using the request params(i.e. groupings of instance members) and performing reflection on the object returned from the DB to get/set the instance fields on the object to return.

I am however, unsure if there is an already existing design pattern for this problem other than a refactor or create a new endpoints for the "lighter" objects. I dont want to argue that case, I just want to discuss for the problem at hand, is reflection a valid method of fulfilling the requirement and if not why not and what are the alternatives.

I believe this solution can cater for change easily, Only the enum needs updated if instance members change or a restriction grouping needs adapting. The rest layer or data layer requires no change. However I am unsure of the performance impact, i only implemented this today so I haven't been able to benchmark yet.

I guess the real question is; is there a design pattern for partial object creation of unknown member fields at runtime

Below is psuedo of how i implemented the select aspect below.

```
select(MyObj obj){
 //get all the restricted fields from the request
// Instantiate new object
// for each restriction field(i.e. instance member)
//         use reflection to invoke the set method of the new object(partial) passing the get method of the method argument(full object)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found a really nice method for this task leveraging the functional aspect of Java8. Indeed this could also be implemented using an anonymous class pre Java8.
I can make use of this in the Enum and construct each one with a BiConsumer.
I can then implement that copy method while I iterate through the passed in arguments.
Now I have have the behaviour I had with reflection but without the performance impact.

```
public enum RestrictFields {
    R1((source, target) -> {
        target.setA(source.getA());
        target.setB(source.getB());
        target.setC(source.getC());
    }), 
    R2((source, target) -> {
        target.setD(source.D());
    });

    private final BiConsumer<MyObj, MyObj> copier;

    private RestrictFields (final BiConsumer<MyObj, MyObj> copier) {
        this.copier = copier;
    }

    public void copy(final MyObj source, final MyObj target){
        this.copier.accept(source, target);
    }
}
```

Now when in the select clause I can cycle through the passed Enum Values and invoke the copy method and build the restricted object based on that.

```
public Object select(MyObj source) {
        MyObj myobj = new MyObj ();
        if (!restrictedFields.isEmpty()) {
            // Instead of refelction here I can use the biconsumer in the enum

            for (RestrictFields field : restrictedFields) {
                field.copy(source, myobj);
            }
            return myObj;
        }
        return source;

    }
```

Comment: Actually this is sort of an effective java recommended way of associating different behaviour with enums. Which is exactly what Im getting the enum to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object mapper for that
Employee -> name , id, uid, address

Using objectmapper readvaluetotree 
Returns JsonNode/ObjectNode

Select your keys to construct the new json

Json= { "name": "xyz", "id": 101, "uid": "xoz", "address": "xqp street" }

Delete the keys which you don't need using 
jsonNode.remove or delete key

then use the jsonNode to parse back to object
Employee em = objectmapper.readValue( json, Employee.class)

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion @niteshbisht although I may have found an even better more readable, less cost expensive method. Let me know if you agree or can be improved.